# svelte each block grouping results delimma

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have an array called products that contains products. Each product belongs to a category.

```
 product = { category : "shorts", name : "whatever", ...}
```

Now when I iterate over that array in svelte, I use each block

```
{#each products as product}
 <li>
   {product.category} - {product.name}
</li>
{/each}
```

So my results are like this :
shorts - blueshort
shorts - greenshort
shorts - yellowshort

My question is how to group the display the results by category. Like this

```
 shorts
          blueshort
          greenshort
          yellowshort
     hats 
          bluehat
          greenhat
          yellowwhatever
```

Is there a way to do it from the each block or I have to take care of it in the script and then send it to the html?

Is there a way to do that in the each block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group results by category and nested `each` statements:

```
<script>
    let products = [
        { category : "shorts", name : "hat one" },
        { category : "shorts", name : "hat two" },
        { category : "hats", name : "hat one" },
        { category : "hats", name : "hat two" },
    ];
    
    // group products by category
    $: data = products.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        // create key and value of array if hasn't been created yet
        if (!acc[curr.category]) acc[curr.category] = [];
        acc[curr.category].push(curr.name);
        return acc;
    }, {});
</script>

<div>
    {#each Object.entries(data) as item}
    <div>{item[0]}</div>
    <ul>
        {#each item[1] as name}
            <li>{name}</li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
    {/each}
</div>
```

Here is an [example in action](https://svelte.dev/repl/5072d87ef91c4b67a04c85660fe2ea72?version=3.48.0)

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: That didn't just help. That rocked. Thank you so much for such an elegant, complete answer.